# Not calling method OnMessageReceived in xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, google-cloud-messaging, xamarin.android

I am implementing remote notification on android using xamarin.

I am doing POC using [**Walkthrough - Using Remote Notifications in Xamarin.Android**](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/notifications/android/remote_notifications_in_android/)

I am not getting notification on mobile, after registering mobile and send notification through sender using GCM.

Is there any mistake in code? or Can I track my notification to get detail why it is not come in mobile?

**MyGcmListenerService.cs**

```
[Service(Exported = false), IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" })]
public class MyGcmListenerService : GcmListenerService
{
    public override void OnMessageReceived(string from, Bundle data)
    {
        var message = data.GetString("message");
        Log.Debug("MyGcmListenerService", "From:    " + from);
        Log.Debug("MyGcmListenerService", "Message: " + message);
        SendNotification(message);
    }
....
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.yourcompany.LeaveApplication" android:installLocation="auto" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.yourcompany.LeaveApplication.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <permission android:name="com.yourcompany.LeaveApplication.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <application android:label="XamarinLeaveApp" >
        <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="com.yourcompany.LeaveApplication" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
  </application>

</manifest>
```

**Message Sender's code**

```
var jGcmData = new JObject();
var jData = new JObject();

jData.Add("message", MESSAGE);
jGcmData.Add("to", "/topics/global");
jGcmData.Add("data", jData);

var url = new Uri("https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
try
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation(
            "Authorization", "key=" + API_KEY);

        Task.WaitAll(client.PostAsync(url,
            new StringContent(jGcmData.ToString(), Encoding.Default, "application/json"))
                .ContinueWith(response =>
                {
                    var response1 = response;
                   // Console.WriteLine(response);
                    //Console.WriteLine("Message sent: check the client device notification tray.");
                }));
    }
}
```

RegistrationIntentService.cs

```
[Service(Exported = false)]
class RegistrationIntentService : IntentService
{
    static object locker = new object();

    public RegistrationIntentService() : base("RegistrationIntentService") { }

    protected override void OnHandleIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        try
        {
            Log.Info("RegistrationIntentService", "Calling InstanceID.GetToken");
            lock (locker)
            {
                var instanceID = InstanceID.GetInstance(Application.Context);

                var token =  instanceID.GetToken(
                    "<project number", GoogleCloudMessaging.InstanceIdScope, null);

                Log.Info("RegistrationIntentService", "GCM Registration Token: " + token);
                SendRegistrationToAppServer(token);
                Subscribe(token);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.Debug("RegistrationIntentService", "Failed to get a registration token");
            return;
        }
    }

    void SendRegistrationToAppServer(string token)
    {
        // Add custom implementation here as needed.
    }

    void Subscribe(string token)
    {
        var pubSub = GcmPubSub.GetInstance(Application.Context);
        pubSub.Subscribe(token, "/topics/global", null);
    }
}
```

Comment: I noticed that you have commented out the response in your sending code. Are you getting a message id in the response indicating a successful send?

Comment: It is just Console.WriteLine so commented out. BTW response was success..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the `RegistrationIntentService.cs` file, you use `Application.Context` instead of `this`. It should be equivalent, but can you try?

Also, I do not see in your code the `protected override void OnCreate` method that registers the `RegistrationIntentService` intent. Didn't you paste it here or did you forget to implement it?

HTH